# How to return array() in vba function to use it in cells Array formulas (matricial formula) : for split texte in multi cells

Tags: arrays, excel, split, excel-formula, vba

I'm writing a  function in VBA to use in excel formula, it's ok if my function return a single value:

```
=MYVALUE(A1)
```

Now I wrote another function which returns an Array(1,2,3,4,...) and I replace my excel formula by Array formula:

```
{=MYARRAY(A1)}
```

But when I stretch the formula, all cells display the *first value of my array*. why ?

Here is my VBA source code (complement.xlam) :

```
Function MYVALUE(x as integer)
    MYVALUE = 123
End Eunction

Function MYARRAY(x as integer)
    MYARRAY = Array(10,20,30)
End Eunction
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14661431/1953175 - I think the same trouble

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14661431/1953175 - is the same trouble
but the answer is not good, it only works in this specific case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array formulas need use like that

my VBA to split text in multi cells

```
Function EXPLODE_V(texte As String, delimiter As String)
    EXPLODE_V = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(texte, delimiter))
End Function
Function EXPLODE_H(texte As String, delimiter As String)
    EXPLODE_H = Split(texte, delimiter)
End Function
```

1. Select region `C3:C7` this define the vector direction.
2. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit on the spot and type the following formula: `=EXPLODE_V($B$3;" ")`
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> ( *INSTEAD of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd>* ) - this will define an ARRAY formula and will result in `{=EXPLODE_V($B$3;" ")}` brackets around it (but do NOT type them manually!).

   [image: sample of split cells texte]

Comment: same as my solution just a more specific implementation?

Comment: ...plus an explanation on how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

the reason is that your vector actually is being displayed horizontally, if you create an array formula horizontally you will get your numbers. For you to have a vertical vector use the following:

```
Function MYARRAY(x As Integer)

    MYARRAY = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array(10, 20, 30))

End Function
```

Comment: I understand your answer but it does not work for me. the array formula return the first result in all cells (in column or row)

Comment: probably because your not entering the array formula correctly. When you have the formula in one cell select the vector you want populated, F2 and then CTRL SHIFT ENTER. Dont drag down as this will only copy a new instance of the array (hence why you are seeing only the first value)

Answer (score -2):

A cell won't display an array, you would have to translate that array to a range/array of cells on the sheet.  Alternatively, you could try converting the array to a delimited string, which may work as long as you aren't using very large arrays.

```
Public Function MYARRAY(x As Integer)

Dim tmpArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim arrayString As String

tmpArray = Array(10, 20, 30)

For i = LBound(tmpArray) To UBound(tmpArray)
    If arrayString = vbNullString Then
        arrayString = tmpArray(i)
    Else:
        arrayString = arrayString & ", " & tmpArray(i)
    End If
Next

MYARRAY = "{" & arrayString & "}"

End Function
```

Comment: return array just needs transposing, no need for the above.

Comment: Yes i know that, i use matricial formulas (Array formulas)